# Post File To Executable

Tags: c#, post, exe, backend, getfiles

So I'm building a connector-like program (the executable) as the backend of a website, the program is written in Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0) using C#.

Basically, the frontend code will call the executable with parameters (or command line argument), then the program will calls different function and perform the appropriate operation.

Now I ran into an issue with *uploading files*. The website will ask the user to browse for a file, then hit the upload button. Once the upload button is hit, the website will call the executable. My idea is in the executable, somehow get the uploaded file and save a copy on the local server, then perform any modification on the local copy.

Hopefully I explained my case well enough. So my **over all question is**: Is there a way for my executable to basically get the the upload file?

I know there might be other work around such as sending POST request directly to a url, but that's not the case here. With the current setup of the website and the backend code, it is required that I use the standalone executable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If `stdio` (See Slaks' answer) isn't sufficient, then you'll typically need to write the posted file to a temporary file (i.e. in the actual OS temp area), and pass the path of the temp file to the exe. The only other option that leaps to mind is "named pipes", but that is massively overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the incoming file to the executable process' `StandardInput`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you possibly give a example of how to use StandardInput? I'm reading on the MSDN site and I can't really understand how to use it with the upload file. Say the user is trying to upload a file called test1.xlsx, to my exe 'myProgram.exe', with parameter 'op1' & 'op2'. In my code for my executable, should I be using myPorcess.StartInfo.FileName = "test1.xlsx";? and how will the forntend pass the file to the executable? Is it just a parameter specifying the filename or is it a POST reuqest to the exe?

Comment: You don't have any file on disk.  Instead, you need to write the bytes that you receive over the network to stdin: `postFile.Stream.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream)`.